# solr indexing breaks down while indexing large core and the server shut down

Tags: solr

I have to reindex a very large solr core (solr 8.6), because there is no other way to use it for my cms. Anyway, at 47% about 306700 docs indexed, it breaks the indexing process and solr server is no more running. It is always at the same indexing level, at 47 %. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Check the syslog - this sounds like your Solr process being OOM killed because your system runs out of memory.

Comment: After checking what caused SOLR to stop, you might increase the memory or change the commit policy or the index policy (index in batches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to assign more memory to solr, you can do that by starting solr with -m option